# How can I order results from Google places autocomplete?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Firstly please accept my apologies if this article already exists, but my long search efforts hasn't returned anything useful so far.

I'm integrating Google places autocomplete into one of my website, I'm struggling to find the options that will allow us to sort order the results; Currently we have an issue where a user can input the word London and we want London, UK to be the first results not London road in ...!

We still want the user to be able to search by Road, but we don't want this to show above big cities.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction on how to do this with Google Places Autocomplete?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, changing the order result of the autocomplete is not possible.

> The [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) service will return candidate matches based on this string and order results based on their perceived relevance.

The closest you can make is to add a restriction by adding `type` and/or `componentRestriction`. Currently, you can use `componentRestrictions` to filter by country.

Sample code:

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
types: ['(cities)'],
componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
const defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds({ lat: 42.5214071, lng: -70.9310135 });
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  document.querySelector('#autocomplete'), {types: ['geocode'],
   bounds: defaultBounds,
   strictBounds: false
});
```

It will help you more.